# LaTeX command to NOT show citation in List of Figures

Tags: latex

I am writing a report and I was wondering is there a command in LaTeX where I can show a reference to a figure in the main content but not the same in the List of Figures generated at the back?

for example:
In the main chapter

**Figure:1 ABC of XYZ process [citation]**

but the List of Figures generated at the back of the report should show:

**Figure:1 ABC of XYZ process ............. Page number**

In most of my figures I use the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{Image folder/image of interest}
\caption{ABC of XYZ process \cite{citation here}}
\label{fig: for reference purposes}
\end{figure}
```

because of \cite{} the List of Figures shows the cite mark for e.g. [1] or [2] which I do not want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\caption` macro has an optional argument, which is the one which is used in the List of Figures and of Tables.  Thus:

```
\caption[ABC of XYZ process]{ABC of XYZ process \cite{citation here}}
```

The caption in the text would include the citation, but it's the ‘ABC of XYZ process’ which would appear in the LoF.

The [LaTeX wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) has a few more details.